# Dataframe to JSON in tree format?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to create a tree style structure from a dataframe in Python.
The desired output would look something like this:

```
{
"Cat1": {
    "Band1" : {
        "PE1": {
            "1995-01": {
                "GroupCalcs": {
                    "Count": 382.0,
                    "EqWghtRtn": -0.015839621267015727,
                    "Idx_EqWghtRtn": 0.9841603787329842,
                    "Idx_WghtRtn": 0.9759766819565102,
                    "WghtRtn": -0.02402331804348973
                }
            },
            "1995-02": {
                "GroupCalcs": {
                    "Count": 382.0,
                    "EqWghtRtn": -0.015839621267015727,
                    "Idx_EqWghtRtn": 0.9841603787329842,
                    "Idx_WghtRtn": 0.9759766819565102,
                    "WghtRtn": -0.02402331804348973
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am looking for the most efficient way of building this from a Dataframe.  I have 20k+ rows to parse out which currently look like this snippet

[Data Snippett](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1dQTm.png)

I was thinking something like this but I know this is very inefficient.

```
dctcat = {}
for cat in alldf.index.levels[0]:
    dctMktBand = {}
    for mktband in alldf.index.levels[1]:
        dctpe = {}
        for pe in alldf.index.levels[2]:
            dctMonth = {}
            for month in alldf.index.levels[3]:
                dctMonth[month]=alldf.loc[[cat,mktband,pe,month]].filter(items=['Count', 'EqWghtRtn', 'Idx_EqWghtRtn','Idx_WghtRtn', 'WghtRtn']).to_dict()

            dctpe[str(pe)]=dctMonth
        dctMktBand[str(mktband)] = dctpe
    dctcat[str(cat)] = dctpe
```

---

### **Possible Solution**

I stumbled across this article https://gist.github.com/hrldcpr/2012250 and using defauldict(tree) I was able to accomplish what I needed in under 2 seconds.  Which while that sounds long, it is considerably faster than what I had.  Sharing the code below, if someone has updates or improvements on this I would appreciate it.

```
    def tree(): 
        return defaultdict(tree)

    def dicts(t): 
        if isinstance(t ,defaultdict):
            outval = {k: dicts(t[k]) for k in t   } 
        else: 
            outval = t
        return outval

    alldf.set_index(['category','marketCapBand','peGreaterThanMarket','Month'], inplace=True)

   tmp = alldf.filter(items=['Count', 'EqWghtRtn', 'Idx_EqWghtRtn','Idx_WghtRtn', 'WghtRtn']).to_dict('index')

   outjson = tree()
    for k,v in tmp.items():
          (cat,mkb,pe,mon) = k
          outjson[str(cat)][str(mkb)][str(pe)][str(mon)] =  v

    # convert back to dictionary
    outjson = dicts(outjson)
```

Comment: Does `pd.read_json` not do the trick? https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_json.html

Comment: Sorry if it isn't clear, I am trying to write this format from a dataframe, not read in.

Comment: You are basically trying to `groupby` and then `dataframe.to_json()`, this function has `orient` parameter that could potentially give you the layout your looking for.

Comment: Do you have a code example?  for the groupby outputting in a format like this?  I was unable to get that to work properly.